# copy record set in local _RecordsetPtr in C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, c++11, visual-c++

I have `getResults` function and executing a query in C++.

```
int ABC::getResult(char *query)
{
    _CommandPtr     pCom;
    _bstr_t         lv_query;
    lv_query        = (_bstr_t) sqlQuery;

    try
    {
        pCom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
        pCom->ActiveConnection = pConn;
        pCom->CommandType = adCmdText;
        pCom->CommandText = lv_query;
        pCom->CommandTimeout = 60;
        RecordSet = pCom->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText);       
    
    }
    catch(_com_error &e)
    {
        _bstr_t bstrSource(e.Source());
        _bstr_t bstrDescription(e.Description());
        sprintf_s(errStr,sizeof(errStr), "Exception:Failed to get detail from database.");
        
        return ERR_EXCEPPTION;
    }
```

I have to copy the _RecordsetPtr RecordSet of this function which is a public member of ABD class.

I am doing like below:

ABC class will make the connection to Database.

```
    ABC mConnect;
    
    mConnect.getResults(query);
    
    _RecordsetPtr lv_set = std::move(mConnect.RecordSet);

    mConnect.CloseConnection();
```

Above std::move is not working , and I get lv_set as null;
I want to achieve that once I take recordset in local copy , I want to close the DB connection and proceed with local recordset to fetch the results

Is there any way to achieve it?

Update:

no had not implement the move ctor
Rather we have similar function as below,
and it give proper RecordSet when I do

```
 _RecordsetPtr lv_set = std::move(mConnect.RecordSet);

int ABC::getResults (char *sqlQuery) 
{
    _bstr_t         lv_query;
    lv_query        = (_bstr_t) sqlQuery;   
    CString         lv_error_log;

    // Define Other Variables
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    _variant_t index;
    index.vt = VT_I2;


    try
    {
        // Open recordset from Authors table.
        hr = RecordSet.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
        if(FAILED(hr))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        
        RecordSet->CursorLocation = adUseClient;

        // Pass the Cursor type and Lock type to the Recordset.
        RecordSet->Open (lv_query, strConn, adOpenDynamic, 
        adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText);
            
    }

        return QRY_EXECUTE_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Comment: Do you get a non-null value in this line `RecordSet = pCom->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText);` ?

Comment: yes , we get proper value in this line

Comment: Did you defined move ctor for `ABC`? If yes, can you please show the move ctor? Better show the implementation for the class ABC.

Comment: no had not implement the move ctor,

Comment: Please see the original post , I had added a funtion by which move is working, but not in case of getResult function